# Updating CKFinder 3.3 to 3.5 requires a new li8cense

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder, ckfinder3

I have Enterprise license of CKFinder 3 and currently using CKFinder 3.3 with Asp.Net.
.Net Framework 4.6

I upgraded from CKFinder 3.3 to 3.5.2.
For this I had to changed project's targetFramework to .Net Framework 4.6.1

But after updating I see this message "This is a demo version of CKFinder 3" on the page where CKFinder is used.
I didn't get this message on CKFinder 3.3 and I'm using the same license key.
If I revert back to CKFinder 3.3 that message goes away.

It seems that updating from CKFinder 3.3 to 3.5 requires a new license.
But on an old CKFinder forum it's written that purchasing a yearly subscription will let us update CKFinder. https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/License-CkFinder

Do I need to buy a new license to use CKFinder 3.5?

Comment: Probably off-topic for 'questions about programming'.  Maybe ask where you bought the subscription.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.